# rails complex table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i'm having a huge problem with creating this table.

I have a model

**Unit**
id
floor
unitnumber

here is my current code for view

```
<% block.units.each do |unit| %>
....
<% end %>
```

I need to loop through the entire block, get all the unique unitnumber and floor. Create a table like this.

```
BLOCKNO  Unitnumber1  Unitnumber2  Unitnumber3  Unitnumber4  Unitnumber5  Unitnumber6
Floor10   unit_id      unit_id      unit_id      unit_id
Floor9
Floor8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% block.each do |block| %>
  <% block.units.each do |unit| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: sorry that's exactly what i'm doing. my problem now is to take the data and put it into the table as required